# kivy Temp Converter

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to create a Fahrenheit to Celsius program with Kivy. I keep getting 
 an error that compute is not defined. I am not sure why this is happening since it is being defined under . Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for any help.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
<Convert>:
    id: compute
    cols:2
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
GridLayout:
    cols:2
    rows:3 
    Label:
        text: 'Fahrenheit'
    TextInput:
        id: entry
        multiline: False
    Label:
        text: 'Celsius'

    TextInput:
        id: result
        multiline: False

    Button:
        text: 'Convert'
        on_press: compute.celsius(result.text)
'''))

class Convert(GridLayout):
    def Temp(self,celsius):
        celsius = (entry-32) * 0.556
        if celsius:
            try:
                self.result.text = str(eval(celsius))
            except Exception:
                self.result.txt = 'Error'

class ConverApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Convert()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ConverApp().run()
```

Comment: So where is the `celsius()` method defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following errors:

- When you use `compute.celsius()` you are assuming that you have a `celsius()` method in your Convert class but you do not have it.
- You must use the `Temp()` method without passing any arguments to it.
- When using self.result you are assuming that result is a member of the Convert class but it is not. If you want to access an element within the hierarchy tree of the .kv you must do it through the id.

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
<Convert>:
    id: compute
    cols:2
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        rows:3 
        Label:
            text: 'Fahrenheit'
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            multiline: False
        Label:
            text: 'Celsius'

        TextInput:
            id: result
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: 'Convert'
            on_press: root.temp()
'''))

class Convert(GridLayout):
    def temp(self):
        try:
            fahrenheit = self.ids.entry.text
            celsius = (int(fahrenheit)-32) * 0.556
            self.ids.result.text = str(celsius)
        except ValueError:
            self.ids.result.text = 'Error'

class ConverApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Convert()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ConverApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still getting the same error. I am really new to this and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: @YouKnow what error you get, could show me a screenshot of the error.

Comment: File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
 NameError: name 'compute' is not defined

Comment: AttributeError: 'GridLayout' object has no attribute 'temp'

Comment: @YouKnow What version of kivy do you have?

Comment: @YouKnow Have you copied the entire code ?, you can send me the file you use.

Comment: Kivy 1.10.0 is the version. I have copied the entire code.

Comment: @YouKnow It's the same version I have, but you have other errors, I could help you faster through teamviewer.